# SSH to remote server, output to remote file?

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm ssh'ing to a remote server and running a command. This works fine.

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@192.168.0.1 /bin/bash << EOF

cd /usr
ls -lh

EOF
```

But I want to save the output of `ls -lh` to a file on the remote or local server.

I've tried the following but that doesn't seem to do anything locally or remotely.

```
sshpass -p password ssh user@192.168.0.1 /bin/bash << EOF

cd /usr
ls -lh > /home/user/filename

EOF
```

How do I do this ?

Thanks

UPDATE.
Quick update.. the live script will be running multiple commands and I only want the results of one command sending the the file. Thanks

Comment: Safer to use `<< 'EOF'`

Comment: This using that is it messes up variables in the code. Is there any way around that ?

Comment: Your second example should work just fine. If it's not working, do you see any output (such as some sort of error)?